# categorical reason on why sheaf hom is a sheaf

Tags: category-theory, sheaf-theory

limits of sheaves are automatically a sheaf. but for colimits, you need to take colimits pointwisely and then take sheafification.

now sheaf hom is automatically a sheaf but sheaf tensor involoves sheafification. is there a similar "categorical reason" for that?

Comment: Yes, the same reason: sheaf hom is a limit (in the second variable) but sheaf tensor is a colimit (in both variables).

Comment: @QiaochuYuan how do you view sheaf hom as a limit and sheaf tensor as a colimit? I googled after seeing your comment and found that sheaf hom is "exponential object" which satisfies a limit-like universal property. but there is no "coexponential" so how about sheaf tensor?